# Trying to Detect Image Presence in a Library of Images

Tags: opencv

I'm working on a project which wants to be able to determine, given a library of images, which is the most similar to the target image.  After doing some research I decided on using OpenCV to match on descriptors.  I took a simple test case that had two library images and one target image that was a small variant on the first library image.  I compute the keypoints and descriptors for each image, then match the descriptors of each library image to the descriptors of the target image.  I then iterate over the matches to find the average distance, figuring the one with the smaller average distance would be the one that's most similar.  This is, however not working--the average distances are essentially the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This topic is highly researched, whth image descriptors some of the most popular approaches. Google will prove a good friend on this. Also scholar.google.com will help you find more than dozen good articles on the topic

Comment: I understand that it's highly researched.  I'm trying to apply that research, and understand why my application is failing.